# Combining two nested for loops into one

Tags: c, array, iterator

## Description

> What this does is it takes a randomly generated 64x64 stack and checks
>   for overlap within the 64x64 array. Here is an example:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6FVO.jpg. Each color is its own number (0 is
>   black, 1 is yellow, 2 is red, etc.) If the colors overlap, the
>   `colors` array will place a zero for that color in the array. At the
>   end of the program, there will be only one color with a non-zero. In
>   this example, yellow (with color code 1) does not get overlapped at
>   all, so that is the answer. I am trying to see if I can make these two
>   nested loops into a single one rather than doing horizontal first and
>   then vertical. I would like to do both horizontal and vertical
>   simultaneously.

## Question

I have two separate nested for loops that work on the same array of data; one nested for loop for working horizontally, and the other for going vertically. There are conditions that will change the `i` and `j` values within each loop.

- I am struggling to find a way to combine this into a single nested for-loop.

## Code

```
/*                 

This program loads a pile and finds the color of the topmost piece. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEBUG 1 // RESET THIS TO 0 BEFORE SUBMITTING YOUR CODE

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int               PileInts[1024];
   int               NumInts, TopColor=0;
   int  Load_Mem(char *, int *);
   // This allows you to access the pixels (individual bytes)
   // as byte array accesses (e.g., Pile[25] gives pixel 25):
   char *Pile = (char *)PileInts;

   if (argc != 2) {
     printf("usage: ./P1-1 valuefile\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   NumInts = Load_Mem(argv[1], PileInts);
   if (NumInts != 1024) {
      printf("valuefiles must contain 1024 entries\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   if (DEBUG){
     printf("Pile[0] is Pixel 0: 0x%02x\n", Pile[0]);
     printf("Pile[107] is Pixel 107: 0x%02x\n", Pile[107]);
   }

   /* Your program goes here */

  int colors[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};


  // NESTED LOOP 1 - HORIZONTAL
  for (int i=1; i<63; i++){                    //run through 63 rows
    for (int j=1; j<63; j++){                  //run through 63 columns

      int current = Pile[i*64 + j];             //current position in linearized 64x64 array
      int right1 = Pile[i*64+j+1];              //1 right of current position
      int right2 = Pile[i*64+j+2];              //2 right of current position
      //int left = Pile[i*64+j-1];              //left of current position

      // CHECK HORIZONTAL OVERLAP
      if ((current != right1) && (current != 0) && (right1 != 0) && (current == right2)) { // check immediately right + edge case,
        colors[current-1] = 0;                                                     // horizontal edge touches vertical
        j++;
      }

      }
  }


// NESTED LOOP 2 - VERTICAL
for (int j=1; j<63; j++){                    //run through 63 rows
    for (int i=1; i<63; i++){                  //run through 63 columns

      int current = Pile[i*64 + j];            //current position in linearized 64x64 array
      //int above = Pile[(i-1)*64+j];            //above current position
      int below1 = Pile[(i+1)*64+j];            //1 below current position
      int below2 = Pile[(i+2)*64+j];            //2 below current position

      // CHECK VERTICAL OVERLAP
      if ((current != below1) && (current != 0) && (below1 != 0) && (current == below2)) { // check immediately right + edge case,
        colors[current-1] = 0;                                                     // horizontal edge touches vertical
        i++;
      }
  }
}

for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++){
  if (colors[k] != 0){
    TopColor = colors[k];
  }
}

  printf("The topmost part color is: %d\n", TopColor);
   exit(0);
}







  /*
  Constraints:
  1 - each part is composed of horizontal and vertical lines all of the same color
  2 - not all parts have the same number of horizontal and vertical lines
  3 - all horizontal and vertical lines in a part have the same length, 25-45 pixels. 
  4 - a parts horizontal line length is not necessarily the same as its verical line length

  Helpful Information:
  The array PileInts is a 1-D array that represents 64x64 pixels
  Index 0 of PileInts represents index (0,0) on a 64x64 pixeled screen which is the top left corner.
  Index 65 of PileInts represents index (1,0) on a 64x64 pixeled screen
  Index 1023 of PileInts represents index (63,63) on a 64x64 pixeled screen which is the bottom right
  */



/* This routine loads in up to 1024 newline delimited integers from
a named file in the local directory. The values are placed in the
passed integer array. The number of input integers is returned. */

int Load_Mem(char *InputFileName, int IntArray[]) {
   int  N, Addr, Value, NumVals;
   FILE *FP;

   FP = fopen(InputFileName, "r");
   if (FP == NULL) {
      printf("%s could not be opened; check the filename\n", InputFileName);
      return 0;
   } else {
      for (N=0; N < 1024; N++) {
         NumVals = fscanf(FP, "%d: %d", &Addr, &Value);
         if (NumVals == 2)
            IntArray[N] = Value;
         else
            break;
      }
      fclose(FP);
      return N;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but since the loop bodies don't depend on previous loop iterations they can be placed in the same loop body (although there may be performance issues).  Assuming you have enough memory allocated for a 64x64 array, `Pile[i*64+j+2]` will access the start of the next row (or past the end for the last row) when `j` is 63.  (Loop 2 will go past the end when `i` is 62 with `i + 2`.)

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! As @1201ProgramAlarm states, _I'm not sure what you're trying to do here_. Code snippets divorced from the rest of your code are not reviewable; they don't have sufficient context. What does this program do? Is it brief enough that we can see it in full? What would you like out of a review?

Comment: @Reinderien I've updated the code and added information. I hope that clears it up even a little more. Thanks!

Comment: Could you update the title to state what your code does functionally instead of what you are technically looking for?

Comment: This code is clearly broken - indexing far outside the bounds of `PileInts`.  Please fix the bugs (compile with a good set of warnings and run under Valgrind or similar) and bring it back for review once it's ready.